# Photos not transferring to shared album

Tags: photos, sharing

I have been trying to pass photos to a shared album on MacOS High Sierra and nothing happens. Sometimes a little ball at the top fills up which seems to indicate it has transferred but it hasn't.

I have tried opening and closing it several times, restarting my laptop and closing the photos agent and still nothing.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi Amanda, welcome to Ask Different! :) Could you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/306995/edit) your question to include the exact version of macOS you're running? Also, is the shared album in question one you created on this laptop, or one you originally created on another device? Finally, when you say you're *trying to pass photos to a shared album*, do you mean you're selecting photos and then dragging them to the album, or are you doing something else such as clicking on the Share icon and then selecting the album?

Comment: Hi Monomeeth,

I'm using MacOS High Sierra. The shared album was created on this device and I have tried to add pictures by selecting them and dragging them and by clicking on the add photos link at the top of the album.